# IronPython - Load script from string in C# 4.0 application

Tags: c#, ironpython, embedding

I have the following code (just a test):

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var runtime = engine.Runtime;

    try
    {                
        dynamic test = runtime.UseFile(@"d:\test.py");

        test.SetVariable("y", 4);
        test.SetVariable("client", UISession.ControllerClient);
        test.Simple();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var eo = engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>();
        Console.WriteLine(eo.FormatException(ex));
    }
```

But I would like to load the script from a string instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString` to load the script into the scope from a string, rather than a file.

```
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("def helloworld():\r\n");
     sb.Append("    print \"hello world\"\r\n");
     string code = sb.ToString();
     ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();         
     ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.File);
     ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
     source.Execute(scope);
     Func<object> func = scope.GetVariable<Func<object>>("helloworld");
     Console.WriteLine(func());
```

Comment: Hey,
This is getting closer, I will try using it but with the dynamic keyword instead. I'll mark it as the answer if I can get it to work :-)

Comment: Looked into this some more, the problem here is that source.Execute(..) always returns null. 
The return type is dynamic, but the value is null. Runtime.UseFile(...) does return a value, I wonder why.

Answer (score 3):

Might this example at the IronPython Cookbook help?  It is on how to call your python class methods from c#...but it contains a working example of loading a script from a file as well.  The example works on IronPython 2.6 (you have to be careful which version as they have been changing the Hosting around quite a bit).

http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Using_Python_Classes_from_.NET/CSharp_IP_2.6

Comment: isn't my answer essentially the same as Tom E's?  Is it because of the link, or is it because Tom's answer is better focused?  Not complaining...just curious.

Comment: For me, sample code is preferable to a link, even if the code is copied & pasted. It's that little bit of extra effort that earns the vote.